# Perl : calculation of time in format hh:mm:ss,sss

Tags: perl, time, format, milliseconds

I need to calculate the time difference between these two variables in Perl :

```
my $end = "17:23:31,576";
my $start = "17:23:30,858";
```

How do I calculate the time difference (`$end - $start`) ? It's important the the returned value keeps the same format.

I would prefer, ideally, to do that with a native function

I've already tried packages like `Time::Piece;` and `DateTime::Format::Strptime`; but couldn't make it work.

Comment: "I've already tried packages like `Time::Piece;` and `DateTime::Format::Strptime;` but couldn't make it work." Please show exactly *what* you tried and we can tell you why it didn't work.

Comment: Note that it's impossible to do this reliably in a time zone with DST unless you also have the date to go along with the time.

Comment: I'm hoping someone shows a DateTime::Format::Strptime or DateTime::Format::CLDR based solution (since DateTime does support microseconds where Time::Piece does not) (prods @ikegami)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A DateTime solution, since it has native support for fractional seconds. Once you got the two DateTime objects, you can use the following program:

```
# delta_ms loses nanoseconds, but we need it to convert days into hours.
my ($h, $m, $s) = $dt2->delta_ms($dt1)->in_units(qw( hours minutes seconds ));
my $ns = ( $dt2 - $dt1 )->nanoseconds;

say sprintf '%d:%02d:%02d,%03.0f', $h, $m, $s, $ns/1_000_000;
```

---

Now, let's look at how to get the two DateTime objects. Given the information provided, the best you can do is the following:

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern   => '%H:%M:%S,%3N',
   time_zone => 'floating',
   on_error  => 'croak',
);

my $dt1 = $format->parse_datetime('01:59:58,123');
my $dt2 = $format->parse_datetime('03:01:02,456');
```

Like all other solutions, this won't always give the right answer because the difference can depend on the date and time zone (e.g. due to DST changes), and this information wasn't made available.

If you do have the information available, then you'd use the following, which correctly gives `1:01:04,333` instead of `0:01:04,333` on the day DST starts.

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern   => '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%3N',
   time_zone => 'America/New_York',  # Often: 'local'
   on_error  => 'croak',
);

my $dt1 = $format->parse_datetime('2015-03-09 01:59:58,000');
my $dt2 = $format->parse_datetime('2015-03-09 03:01:02,000');
```

Comment: Arigatou gozaimasu :-)

Answer (score 1):

With Time::Piece, I think you have to handle the milliseconds separately.

```
use Time::Piece;
my $start = "17:23:31,576";
my $end = "17:23:30,858";
my ($start_time,$start_ms) = split /,/, $start;
my ($end_time,$end_ms) = split /,/, $end;
my $difference = Time::Piece->strptime($end_time,'%H:%M:%S') - Time::Piece->strptime($start_time,'%H:%M:%S') + ( $end_ms - $start_ms ) / 1000;
```

To turn the fractional number of seconds back into a formatted time is easy, if messy:

```
my $negative = $difference < 0 ? '-' : '';
$difference = abs $difference;
my $seconds = int $difference;
my $ms = sprintf '%03d', 1000 * ($difference - $seconds);
my $formatted_difference = Time::Piece->gmtime($seconds)->strftime("$negative%H:%M:%S,$ms");
```

Comment: Thank you, but how to convert the `$difference` value (in milliseconds) to the format `hh:mm:ss,sss` ?

Comment: note that your end time is earlier than your start time; I've allowed for that, but it makes the code more complicated

Comment: Sorry, I just misnamed the variables. I'll correct that.

Comment: Thank you for your code. I understood what you did ! (y)
Just out of curiosity, I tried this time to add two variables `00:35:31,576` and `00:02:30,858`, but I get this error : `Invalid rhs of addition: Thu Jan  1 00:02:30 1970 at time_diff.pl`. Do you have any idea of what it means ?

Comment: Time::Piece uses overloading to support subtraction of two times to get the difference between them.  It also supports adding a number of seconds to a time.  It doesn't support adding two times together; what would that even mean?

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. In my case, I have two operations, each one has a starting and an ending time. I need to know : the duration of each operation (thus the time difference), now I need the total duration (duration of operation1 + duration of operation2).

Comment: calculate `$difference` for each pair, add them together, then get the `$formatted_difference` for the total

Comment: I've already calculated the `$difference` for each pair. I'm stuck at "adding them together". You stated that it's not possible with the Time::Piece

Comment: @Sherlock It is possible with `Time::Piece` (technically, `Time::Seconds`; the difference of two `Time::Piece` objects is a `Time::Seconds` object), and you're misunderstanding ysth's explanation. You can add two *durations*, but not two *times* (there's a difference). But this is straying from your original question; you should ask a new question if you're having trouble with something you didn't originally ask about.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot : Actually, the durations I have are the same as the "times". As I said, I have `00:35:31,576` and `00:02:30,858` (they stand for durations, but technically, they're times.

Comment: @Sherlock That doesn't make any sense. The difference between two times is a duration. You can write a duration in `hh:mm:ss` format, but that doesn't make it a time, just like you can put lipstick on a pig, but it's still a pig.

Answer (score 1):

Just a similar, but more manual approach, caclulating the diff manually, and using gmtime to split it out into hours, minutes and seconds. Handling fractions manually, as gmtime only uses integers.

This is kind of reinventing Time::Piece, so I actually prefer ysth's solution.

```
my $start = "17:23:30,858";
my $end   = "17:23:31,576";
#split by ; and ,
my ($h_start,$m_start,$s_start, $frac_start) = split(/[:,]/, $start) ;
my ($h_end,$m_end,$s_end, $frac_end) = split(/[:,]/, $end) ;

#find #seconds since epoch (whatever it is)
my $start_time = $s_start + $m_start * 60 + $h_start * 3600;
my $end_time   = $s_end   + $m_end   * 60 + $h_end   * 3600;
my $diff_sec   = $end_time - $start_time;

#handling fractions independently, paying attention to negative fractions
#0.0 + first to force float
my $diff_frac = 0.0 + "0.$frac_end" - "0.$frac_start";
if ($diff_frac < 0) {
    $diff_frac++;
    $diff_sec--;
}
#then using the build in function to convert from seconds from epoch to sec min hrs
#using gmt (not local) to convert without timezones and daylight savings...
my ($s_diff,$m_diff,$h_diff) = gmtime( $diff_sec);

#and finally manual formatting using sprintf    
my $diff_date = sprintf("%02u:%02u:%02u,%03u", $h_diff,$m_diff,$s_diff,$diff_frac*1000);
print $diff_date;
```